# VBA Date filter

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a problem with a date filter. VBA doesn't work on it for some reason, if i do the exact same procedure manually, the filter works fine but with the VBA the filter returns "nothing", which is false.

So basically i have date values in column 8 and i want to see the ones that are after my ComparisonDate.

Any ideas on why this is not working?

```
Sub Datefilter()

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

headerRow = Range("Headers").Row
lRow = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row
ComparisonDate = Sheets("Start").Range("Date_CP").Value

Range("A" & headerRow & ":M" & lRow).AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & ComparisonDate

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try to add `Operator:=xlFilterValues` to your `AutoFilter` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume *ComparisonDate* is indeed a date then you need to add to your code the following line and convert the date to a double value.

```
ComparisonDate = CDbl(ComparisonDate)
```

that means your code should look like that

```
Sub Datefilter()

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

    headerRow = Range("Headers").Row
    lRow = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    ComparisonDate = Sheets("Start").Range("Date_CP").Value
    ComparisonDate = CDbl(ComparisonDate)

    Range("A" & headerRow & ":M" & lRow).AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & ComparisonDate

End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like you're the one saving me all the time? Thank you once again! :)

Comment: Small heads-up to OP: you are using implicit cell references and Active sheet, which is rarely a good idea. Also you won't need the check on AutoFiltermode. @Carlsberg789. Btw, the reason why it doesn't work without Cdbl is usually another version of Excel than en_us. I for example have Dutch date formatting which means I also have to use this technique.

Comment: Ohh i see. It's actually triggered by a button if that's what you mean, i'm aware that users might not like "automatic" features that are triggered by certain actions. :)